# How to change wordpress permalinks without give 404 error?

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

i want to change my wp post permalinks from:

```
/post/%post_id%.php
```

to:

```
    /%post_id%/%postname%
```

But it makes 404 errors from last post links. How can i fix it?
i used this Plugins:
Dean's permalink migration,
Simple 301 Redirect And 
Change Permalink Helper
But They do not work or work incompletely. please help me.
Thanks

Comment: rename your htacess file and change the permalink structure (changing permalink structure will create new htacess file it will prevent 404 problem)

Comment: When you say "work incompletely" what do you mean by that?

Comment: I Want that when a user went to a post by the previous link, redirect to the current link.

Comment: There is no one answer?